# Is there a standard file naming convention for key-value pairs in filename?

Tags: machine-learning, filenames, human-computer-interface, human-readable, long-filenames

I have multiple data files that are named after what they contain. For example

```
machine-testM_pid-1234_key1-value1.log
```

There are keys and values separated by - and _. Is there a better syntax for this? Are there parsers that automatically read these kinds of files/filenames?

The idea here is that the filenames are human **and** machine readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no standard file naming convention for key-values.

Answer (score 2):

8 years later...

I would suggest that you look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

They aren't pretty filenames, but you wouldn't have to re-invent the wheel with for example converting to dict/json since there are well-tested methods for parsing query strings, for example in the requests library.

There's a related question over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44153/good-style-practices-for-separators-in-file-or-directory-names as well that contains some useful information that contains some ideas for better visual separators (`_-_` and `___`) that might be better in this case

Answer (score 0):

the most basic type of `KEY=VALUE` files with pretty much strict syntax i know would be:

- **.properties** mostly for java configuration-files, they allow comments
- **.env** mostly for unix, systemd-service environment files, they allow comments
- **.ini** mostly for c#,python,... applications, they allow comments and `[sections]` aswell

(you can mix and still use them though, that's just my experience how developers are naming their stuff based on libraries e.t.c.)

and there are a lot more with **slightly different syntax**, for example

- **.json** files and/or syntax `"key":"value"`
- **.yaml** files and/or syntax `key: "value"`
- **.xml** files and/or syntax `<key>value</key>`
- custom stuff based on the application can be key=value too, but doesn't have to ... look for something like **.cfg** , **.conf** , **.config** , **.preferences**, **.settings**,  ...

hope that helps.