# While splitting datasets why do people follow naming convention?

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)
```

In this example `(X_train, X_test)` `X` mentioned as uppercase where as 
`(y_train, y_test)` here `y` mentioned in lowercase.

Is there any compelling reason to follow that naming convention?

Comment: I don't see **any** logical reason to follow this convention of uppercase X and lowercase y. Most of the new learners when introduced to data science starts by following some existing examples which traces back to the official sklearn docs and hence, I think, the legacy/convention continues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard file naming convention for key-value pairs in filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087079/is-there-a-standard-file-naming-convention-for-key-value-pairs-in-filename)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly, and used "backticks" around the variable references to make them distinct from natural language - please see the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: @Raman My question is not related to filename conventions, hence it is not duplicate.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/389395/232706, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17598/55122.

Answer (score 6):

This comes from the case where you have multiple features (inputs)  and one response variable (output). Then, the input `X` is a matrix with `number_of_features` columns and `number_of_samples` rows, and the output  `y` is a column vector with `number_of_samples` elements. Following the convention of naming matrices with uppercase letters and vectors with lowercase letters, which is widely used in mathematics and/or related fields, it makes sense that `X` has to be uppercase and `y` has to be lowercase.

If you only have one feature, so the input is a column vector and not a matrix, then `x` should be lowercase. And if you have multiple response variables and the output is a matrix, then `Y` should be uppercase.

Finally, using more descriptive names than `X` and `y` is always a good idea. Then, following the PEP 8 convention uf using snake_case for variable names - or whatever the style guide you are following recommends - is the way to go.